# Python script that make my .bash_aliases file MUCH more readable and clear

Tags: python, python-3.x

My .bash_aliases file contains several aliases.
In the beginning, when I wanted to see the aliases, I print the .bash_aliases file,

The output wasn't readable at all, so I created a python script to make it better.
To call my python script, I use the alias `print_aliases_manual`

What is the most pythonic way to write the following script?

Here is my python script:

```
class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'


with open('/home/pi/.bash_aliases', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        if r'##' in line:
            print(f'{bcolors.HEADER}{bcolors.UNDERLINE}{bcolors.BOLD}{line}{bcolors.ENDC}')
        elif r'#' in line:
            print(f'{bcolors.WARNING}{line}{bcolors.ENDC}')
        elif r'alias' in line:
            drop_alias = line.replace('alias', '')
            new_line = drop_alias.replace('=', '   ')
            print(f'{bcolors.OKGREEN}{new_line}')
        else:
            print(f'{line}')
```

Here is my bash_aliases file:

```
### Aliases list divided by category:

## General commands:
alias cdd="cd /home/pi/Desktop/speedboat/"
alias dc="sudo docker-compose"
alias pm2="sudo pm2"

## Cellular related commands:
alias pc="ping -I wwan0 www.google.com"
alias qmi="sudo qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 -p"

## AWS relaeted commands:
alias dlogs="sudo docker logs -f iot_service"

## Git commands:
alias gp="sudo git pull"
alias gc="sudo git checkout"

## scripts to run when deleting speedboat directory is needed:

# copying files to Desktop
alias stodtop="sudo -E sh /home/pi/Desktop/speedboat/scripts/copy_files_to_desktop.sh"
# copying files from Desktop
alias sfromdtop="sudo -E sh /home/pi/Desktop/speedboat/scripts/copy_files_from_desktop_to_speedboat.sh"

## verifications test and updates scripts
# run speedboat verifications tests
alias sinsta="sudo sh /home/pi/Desktop/speedboat/scripts/installation_verification.sh"
# run local unittests
alias slocalt="sudo sh /home/pi/Desktop/speedboat/scripts/run_local_unittest.sh"
# pull os updates from git and execute
alias supdate="sudo sh /home/pi/Desktop/speedboat/scripts/updates-speedboat.sh"

## speedboat start and stop scripts (dockers and PM2)
alias startr="sudo sh /home/pi/Desktop/speedboat/scripts/start_speedboat.sh"

alias stopr="sudo sh /home/pi/Desktop/speedboat/scripts/stop_speedboat.sh"

## AWS related scripts:

alias secrl="sudo sh /home/pi/Desktop/speedboat/scripts/ecr-login.sh"

alias slog="sudo sh /home/pi/Desktop/speedboat/scripts/log_register.sh"

## Command to run speedboat aliases manual:
alias print_aliases_manual="python3 /home/pi/Desktop/speedboat/verification/test_verification_speedboat/colored_aliases_manual.py"
```

Answer (score 10):

**`print`**

f-Strings are a great and convenient tool for including variables and calculations in strings. I'd say they're generally not needed when printing only variables. For example

```
print(f'{bcolors.WARNING}{line}{bcolors.ENDC}')
```

could become

```
print(bcolors.WARNING, line, bcolors.ENDC, sep='')
```

However I'm not sure which of the two is more pythonic, I personally prefer the latter for readability.

You could also consider pulling out formatting into seperate variables to increase readability.

```
HEADER_FORMAT = "".join((bcolors.HEADER, bcolors.UNDERLINE, bcolors.BOLD, "{}", bcolors.ENDC))

print(HEADER_FORMAT.format(line))
```

---

**`in` vs. `startswith`**

I'd recommend using `str.startswith` instead of `str in str` for checking prefixes.

```
if r'##' in line:
```

becomes

```
if line.startswith(r"##"):
```

This is less error-prone and conveys your intentions more explicitly, without the need to look at the source file. As there aren't any escape characters in your prefixes, you also don't need to make it a raw string. You can simply drop the `r`:

```
if line.startswith("##"):
```

Comment: @Reinderien Maybe I‘m looking at the wrong line here, but the second print has its seperator set to an empty string via the sep argument.

Comment: You're right, my apologies

Answer (score 8):

First, a laundry list of things:

- `bcolors` is not only colours; "underline" and "end code" are not colours. Call this perhaps `ANSICodes`, title-case to be PEP8-compliant.
- `'r'` is the default file mode and can be omitted
- Do not hard-code your home directory
- You don't need `readlines`; iterate over the file object
- As @riskypenguin suggests, `in` is not the right tool here. Consider `startswith` for your header and comments, and a regex for the aliases.
- Pre-binding to format calls will clean things up a little
- Try piping your output through `less` and observe the fireworks. You need to be assured that your `stdout` is a real TTY.
- Consider making a fixed field width for your alias keys instead of four absolute spaces

### Example

Note that I'm using a different file path from you.

```
import re
from os import getenv
from pathlib import Path
from sys import stdout
from typing import Callable

# Terrible workaround for Pycharm
DECORATE = stdout.isatty() or getenv('PYCHARM_HOSTED')

RE_ALIAS = re.compile(r'^alias (.+)="(.+)"')


class ANSICodes:
    RED = '\033[91m'
    GREEN = '\033[92m'
    YELLOW = '\033[93m'
    BLUE = '\033[94m'
    PINK = '\033[95m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'

    @classmethod
    def decorate(cls, *codes: str) -> Callable[[str], str]:
        return ''.join((
            *codes, '{}', cls.ENDC,
        )).format


header1 = ANSICodes.decorate(ANSICodes.PINK, ANSICodes.UNDERLINE, ANSICodes.BOLD)
comment = ANSICodes.decorate(ANSICodes.YELLOW)
alias = ANSICodes.decorate(ANSICodes.GREEN)


def transform(line: str) -> str:
    match = RE_ALIAS.match(line)
    if match:
        k, v = match.groups()
        line = f'{k:7} {v}'
        if DECORATE:
            return alias(line)
        return line

    if DECORATE:
        if line.startswith('##'):
            return header1(line)
        if line.startswith('#'):
            return comment(line)

    return line


def main():
    path = Path('.bash_aliases')
    # path = Path('~/.bash_aliases').expanduser()
    with path.open() as f:
        for line in f:
            print(transform(line.rstrip()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: THX!!! That is genuinely beneficial. @Reinderien, can you please explain how to pipe the stdout throw less?

Comment: @Monty_emma Instead of `print_aliases_manual`, you'd have `print_aliases_manual | less`.  The `|` is a pipe.